# coldfusion insert xml element

Tags: xml, xpath, coldfusion

I am trying to use CF to add a binding the my IIS configuration (applicationHost.config). I can drill through the XML and view all of the sites. I can then select a site and view all of the bindings currently for that site. I then need to be able to add a new binding (insert new element into the bindings node for that particular site).

Here is what I have so far...

```
<cfset variables.theXML = session.theXML>
<cfset bindings = xmlSearch(variables.theXML,"//site[@id=#val(form.siteid)#]/bindings/binding")>
<cfset f = structNew()>
<cfset f.bindingInformation = "*:80:#form.binding#">
<cfset f.protocol = "http">
<cfset arrayAppend(bindings, XmlElemNew(variables.theXML, "binding"))>
<cfset bindings[arrayLen(bindings)].XmlAttributes = f>
```

I can dump bindings and see my new element in there just fine. The problem is that bindings is now it's own variable and no longer associated with the full XML doc. I thought I could swap out the bindings array for the specific site using basic xpath, but I need to be able to swap it out dynamically based on the site's id. I guess I could loop over the full xml and insert once I have found the location to insert, but that seems like a lot of processing for something so simple. I am thinking I may have overlooked something obvious here.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit unclear. What do you want to swap out? Can't you simply overwrite the values in-place?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an appropriate job for a ColdFusion server from a security perspective. The `applicationHost.config` is an operating system file that defines how IIS works. I'm pretty sure you need administrative rights to make any changes. You don't really want to give your ColdFusion service admin rights to that file, do you? While your intentions may be fair, if the server is ever compromised your new friend will also have admin rights to that file.

Comment: @Tomalak - I am actually adding a record to the array of bindings. But since I had to use XMLSearch to return that array of bindings, altering the array is not altering the XML Doc, just the variable which is now holding the array. I would like to figure out how to do this, but on the same token I am also thinking that Miguel-F has a very valid point which is, that my risk is not worth my reward in this scenario.

Comment: Just use the regular DOM methods. From any particular binding node, use `.parentNode.appendChild(newNode)`